# How to validate the object state in method or property entry using PostSharp?

Tags: validation, methods, properties, state, postsharp

How can I validate the object state (example: value of a bool field) in a method entry using PostSharp?

Is that also possible for a property getter or setter?
Possible for auto-properties too?

I know how to validate method parameters via custom contracts and how to intercept a method via methodboundry but I don't know how to pass a state validation rule from aspect attribute to method entry body.

**My use case:**

I want all initialized checks in Method1, 2 and 3 to be handled with an aspect.

Without aspect:

```
class MyClass
{
   bool Initialized;

   void Init()
   {
       //do stuff;
       Initialized = true;
   }

   void Method1()
   {
       if (!Initialized) throw AwesomeException("Awesome text");

       //do stuff;
   }

   void Method2()
   {
       if (!Initialized) throw AwesomeException("Awesome text");

       //do stuff;
   }

   void Method3()
   {
       if (!Initialized) throw AwesomeException("Awesome text");

       //do stuff;
   }
}
```

with aspect:

```
   [Conditional( <<somehow define condition field here>> Initialized, "Awesome text"]
   void Method1()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }

   [Conditional( <<magic>> Initialized, "Awesome text"]
   void Method2()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }

   [Conditional( <<magic>> Initialized, "Awesome text"]
   void Method3()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }
```

Comment: You can apply contracts to fields and (auto)properties as well. This is possible with PostSharp: `[Required] string f1;`, `[Required] public string P1 { get; set; }`. Validation is triggered when a value is assigned to field or property. Does it solve your needs? If not, please could you describe your use case in more detail?

Comment: I added my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution requires several a little bit advanced PostSharp features.

You need to be able to access a "condition field" from your aspect and you need to be able to configure which field is the "condition field". Unfortunately C# allows you to specify constant expressions as attribute arguments. The only way (I know about) is using a string to specify the "condition field" name:

```
   [Conditional( "Initialized", "Awesome text"]
   void Method1()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }
```

The problem is that intellisense doesn't work with strings but you can validate existence of the field in your aspect.

You can import any field of a target class by using [ImportLocationAdviceInstance](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_importlocationadviceinstance) and implementing [IAdviceProvider](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_iadviceprovider):

```
[PSerializable]
public class ConditionalAttribute : InstanceLevelAspect, IAdviceProvider
{
    private string conditionFieldName;
    private string awesomeText;
    public ILocationBinding ConditionBindingField;

    public ConditionalAttribute(string conditionFieldName, string awesomeText)
    {
        this.conditionFieldName = conditionFieldName;
        this.awesomeText = awesomeText;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AdviceInstance> ProvideAdvices(object targetElement)
    {
        var targetType = (Type) targetElement;
        var bindingFieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField("ConditionBindingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (
            var field in
            targetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            if (field.Name == conditionFieldName)
            {
                if (field.FieldType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool)))
                {
                    yield return new ImportLocationAdviceInstance(bindingFieldInfo, new LocationInfo(field));
                    yield break;
                }
                {
                    Message.Write(MessageLocation.Of(targetType), SeverityType.Error, "ERR002", $"{targetType.Name} contains {field.FieldType.Name} {conditionFieldName}. {conditionFieldName} has to be bool.");
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }

        Message.Write(MessageLocation.Of(targetType), SeverityType.Error, "ERR001", $"{targetType.Name} doesn't contain {conditionFieldName}");
    }
}
```

Now, `ConditionBindingField` either contains binding to the "condition field", or PostSharp emits ERR001 or ERR002 if the "condition field" of given name doesn't exists or is declared with other type than `bool`.

The next step is intercept target class methods with validation code:

```
[OnMethodInvokeAdvice]
[MethodPointcut("SelectMethods")]
public void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
{
    bool conditionFieldValue = (bool)ConditionBindingField.GetValue(args.Instance);
    if (!conditionFieldValue)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(awesomeText);
    }

    args.Proceed(); // call original method body
}
```

PostSharp intercepts each method provided by `SelectMethods` method with the code in OnInvoke method. The problem is that you don't want to intercept `Init` methods with the "condition field" check, otherwise the call to this method would throw an exception with the "Awesome text" and it would not be possible to initialize a class. So you have to mark somehow methods that cannot be intercepted. You can either use convention and give the same name to all `Init` methods or you can mark `Init` method with an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class InitAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

You can use [MethodPointcut](http://doc.postsharp.net/advices#Pointcuts) to select public instance methods without `Init` attribute:

```
private IEnumerable<MethodInfo> SelectMethods(Type type)
{
    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public;

    return type.GetMethods(bindingFlags)
        .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InitAttribute)).Any());
}
```

Conditional aspect usage example:

```
[Conditional("Initialized", "Awesome text")]
class MyClass
{
   bool Initialized;

   [Init]
   void Init()
   {
       Initialized = true;
   }

   void Method1()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }
}
```

EDIT: It is possible to mark "condition field" by an attribute instead of specifying its name as string:

```
[Conditional("Awesome text")]
class MyClass
{
   [ConditionField]
   bool Initialized;

   [Init]
   void Init()
   {
       Initialized = true;
   }

   void Method1()
   {
       //do stuff;
   }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. I didn't test it yet but I'll mark it as correct answer. I'll report back if I have any problem when implementing it. Thank you!!

Comment: Also, I can use nameof keyword instead of "Initialized" string. That gives me a little bit of intellisense support.